# Laravel - endpoint para editar datos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-4

tengo un formulario donde cargo los datos en una plantilla blade y muestro 2 capturas de imagen, entonces lo que hago es mostrar dos componentes "dropzone" que sirve para subir imagenes drag&drop, hasta aquí todo bien, el problema lo tengo en el controlador que recibe los datos del formulario, ahora mismo si el usuario sobrescribe las dos imágenes perfecto porque las recibe el controlador y hace el update.
Pero en el caso que el usuario solo quiere actualizar una imagen, una la envía correctamente pero la otra la envia como "null".

Mi pregunta es como trato esto en el controlador? Es decir el controlador debería poder recibir "N" parámetros pero solo actualizarlos cuando tengan valor.

```
 /**
 * Upload images
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param int $id
 * @return ResponseFactory|Response
 */
public function uploadImages(Request $request, $id)
{

    $promoExists = Promocion::find($id);

    if (null === $promoExists) {
        return response('Promocion no válida',404);
    }

    $imagen_esp = $request->get('imagen_esp');
    $imagen_pt = $request->get('imagen_pt');

    if (null !== $imagen_esp) {
        $category = '/'. $id . '/';
        $imagen_esp = str_replace("/", $category, $imagen_esp);
    }

    if (null !== $imagen_pt) {
        $category = '/'. $id . '/';
        $imagen_pt = str_replace("/", $category, $imagen_pt);
    }

    try {
        Promocion::where('id', '=', $id)
            ->update([
                'imagen_esp' => $imagen_esp,
                'imagen_pt' => $imagen_pt,
            ]);
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $aux = $exception;
    }

    return response('Imágenes subidas correctamente',200);

}
```

Gracias

Comment: Que versión de Laravel usas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes el registro existente:

```
$promoExists = Promocion::find($id);
```

De hecho puedes ponerle

```
$promoExists = Promocion::findOrFail($id);
```

Y te ahorras tirar el error "no encontrado" a mano.

Las imagenes actuales son:

```
$imagen_esp = $promoExists->imagen_esp;
$imagen_pt = $promoExists->imagen_pt;
```

Si viene una imagen nueva, sólo entonces la reemplazas.En caso contrario no tocas el registro actual. Al final del método actualizas el registro y en el peor de los casos, si no se mandó nada de nada, habrás persistido los valores iniciales.

Comment: Gracias, solucionado. 1000 gracias